# select several column use group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, select, group-by, dplyr

I want to select several column easily. please help me.

Now I use like this:

```
dplyr::group_by(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
```

I hope use like this. But present error:

```
dplyr::group_by(iris, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

select() can select column use colon(:)
    dplyr::select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)

But group_by() cannot column use colon(:)

```
dplyr::group_by(iris, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

select() can use colon(:) to select column,
but why group_by() use colon?

Comment: Try these: `library(dplyr); iris %>% group_by(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)` OR  `dplyr::group_by(iris,Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)`. Notice the difference ?, in first case we start with dataset and try group_by without name of dataset as input whereas in second approach we need dataset name as input. Hope this helps and note that 1) grouping with all variables in dataset makes little sense 2) to pass variables you can use `everything()` instead of listing out variables

Comment: your approach with `:` is possible for `dplyr:select()`, e.g. `select(iris, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)`, but not for `group_by()`

Comment: I imagine `group_by` doesn't let you do this because one would not normally group by more than two or three variables anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish something similar using the `*_` version, though it may take a bit more thought to get the right values. Here, you want the first four columns, so this should work:

```
iris %>% group_by_(.dots = names(.)[1:4])
```

Shows:

```
Source: local data frame [150 x 5]
Groups: Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width [149]

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

It would probably work even better to save the column names first, which would give you even more control, e.g.,

```
colsToSave <- names(iris)[1:4]

iris %>% group_by_(.dots = colsToSave)
```

Gives the same result, but could let you set your own ranges. You could even use `select` to generate to columns you want, then just save the names, though that is likely overkill.

```
colsToSave <- iris %>% select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>% names
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did that answer your question, or is there some piece still missing preventing you from accepting the answer?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is struggling with this in 2023, you can just use `pick` within `group_by` to access tidy-select functionality.

```
iris %>% dplyr::group_by(pick(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width))
```

Comment: You can use the native pipe here `|>` to avoid loading magrittr.